# TextView inside TableRow not scrolling?

Tags: android, xml, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

I have some confusion as I have a scrollable fragment, inside which TableLayout is present.Now the thing is that a textview in the end is not showing the full text(huge rawtext).Although I am using  textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()) too, but it is still not working. Any help?

The xml code is below pasted.

```
  <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pbackground"
android:orientation="vertical">
  <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

  ////////////////////////////// some table rows...
<TableRow
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="left">
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="pojodjfpojsdpoj
            fposdjfpjsdpofjposdjofpjsodppoj
            odjfpojsdpojfposdjfpjsdpofjposdjofpjs
            odppojodjfpojsdpojfposdjfpjsdpofjposdj
            ofpjsodppojodjfpojsdpojfposdjfpjsdpofjp
            fpojsdpojfposdjfpjsdpofjposdjofpjsodp"

            android:textColor="#000" />
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please put some your code so that it is more clear.

Comment: spelling mistakes and rephrased the question line.

Comment: The code is pasted above,the problem exists in the textView which is not showing the whole text